# SonarQube server new quality profile checkstyle rules

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

While trying to create a new quality profile using our own checkstyle_rules.xml and even using sun issued checkstyle_rules, I get errors like below:

For sun checkstyle rules xml

```
Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile:
checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RegexpSinglelineCheck
```

For Google checkstyle rules xml

```
The definition of the profile 'null' (language 'null') contains multiple occurrences of the
'checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.blocks.RightCurlyCheck' rule. 
The plugin which declares this profile should fix this.
```

I could find documentation regarding xml should give templates, and we need to create actual rules on top of that.

How can I go about creating checkstyle rules for SONAR and how to convert our checkstyle_rules to template

Answer (score 0):

you cannot play a template rule, you have first to create your own rule based on the template rule. Then in your quality profile you associate your new rule based on the template, not the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this concerns only **template rules**. Example with rule "Boolean Expression Complexity" (checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.metrics.BooleanExpressionComplexityCheck) See Sonar Checkstyle import: Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile for more details.

there is **no activation button** for these rules,you can either create them with **default properties** or with your **custom properties**.

In your case **RegexpSinglelineCheck** template rule have to be created in sonarqube,you cannot activate it by importing an xml file(this is a actually a limitation).And a rule cannot be converted into template,a template can neither be created nor be deleted(there are about **44 rule templates** currently in sonarqube checkstyle repository).

I would suggest activating them with the **properties used by google**(but some of them are not used by google so activate them with according to your needs)

refer this link:https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml